# Incrementing the left value in a style sheet with Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, stylesheet

I have the following MVC Razor code

```
@{
    int counter = 50;

    foreach (var item in Model.Items) {
        <div class="wall-image" id="@("DRAG0"+counter)" onDblClick="makeNew()" style="position:absolute; left:370px; top:165px; ">
            <img src="@item.Picture.ImageUrl" title="@("DRAG0"+counter)" />
        </div>
        counter = counter + 50;
    }
}
```

It concatenates the id of an image giving each image a unique identifier which works fine:

id="@("DRAG0"+counter)"

What I would like to do is add the value of counter to **left:370px** in the same way, can that be done inside a style?

Comment: Can you more explain your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve it by using `ToString()` and adding `margin-left`

```
margin-left:@(counter.ToString()+"px");
```

I wanted each image to display counter… px to the left of the last

```
@{
    int counter = 0;
    string image = "";

    foreach (var item in Model.Items) {

        <div class="wall-image" id="@("DRAG0"+counter)" onDblClick="makeNew()" style="position:absolute; left:370px; top:275px; margin-left:@(counter.ToString()+"px");">
            <img src="@image" title="@item.ProductName" />
        </div>
        counter = counter + 135;
    }
}
```